# Symfony 4.3 translation update not working with container

Tags: symfony4

In my controller, I use

```
$this->get('session.flash_bag')
    ->add('error', $this->get('translator')->trans('User cannot be activated',[],'messages'));
```

After team

```
php bin/console translation: update --dump-messages ru --domain=messages
```

I do not see new translations. Through tests, I realized that the container is not loaded and the translation is not visible. If you implement Translator in a method, then everything is fine. How can you do without implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a reason. Just the service **translator** is not in the container. In the end, I injected the dependency into the base controller and use **$this->translator**